# Replace set of characters of every occurrence from a string in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have some silly issue in javascript, am so close in replacing set of characters from a string with a character, but couldn't make it completely.

Here is the code

```
var mystring ="[[{"id":27,"av":20}],[{"id":24,"av":20}],[{"id":28,"av":40}]]";
mystring = mystring.replace('],[', ',');
```

This is replacing the first occurrence of the given characters '],[' with ','
 so the result is

```
"[[{"id":27,"av":20},{"id":24,"av":20}],[{"id":28,"av":40}]]"
```

What am I missing, how can I replace every occurrence of '],[' with ',' ?

Comment: Your string is a syntax error. That said, modifying JSON with string operations is probably not the best way to do things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use regex with the 'g modifier' to perform a global replacement:

```
mystring = mystring.replace(/\],\[/g, ',');
```

Comment: You should explain why a regex with the `g` modifier works differently then replace with a string as a parameter.

Comment: You're right, I just completed my answer to make it more clear

Answer (score 2):

Could use split and join:

```
mystring.split('],[').join(',');
```

Not sure how it compares performance wise though.